# Return plain text JSON request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to call an `ActionResult` and update the value of an img on the page based on the returned result from the `Action`, but for some reason I post to a new page that just prints the string

```
   public ActionResult Favorite(int? id)
    {
        int PId = Convert.ToInt32(pid);
        if (MyDb.CheckExist(Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name),PId))
        {
            var UF = MyDb.GetExist( Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name),PId);
            MyDb.Delete(UF);
            MyDb.Save();
            return Json(new { Url= "/Content/oldimage.png" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        else
        {
            UFs UF = new UFs();
            UF.Id = PId;
            UF.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
            UF.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            MyDb.Add(UF);
            MyDb.Save();
            return Json(new {  Url= "/Content/newimage.png"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);//return favorite image
        }

    }
```

my anchor tag that calls my ajax

```
   <a href='<%= Url.Action("Favorite","Home", new { id = item.Id })%>' class="Image" style="text-decoration:none">
            <img src="/Content/Images/oldimage.png" alt="FavoriteImage" style="height:25px;width:30px"  id="favorite<%:item.Id %>" class="ImageTag" /></a>


  $('.Image').click(function () {

        var id = this.children('.ImageTag').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                 $('#' + id).attr('src', data.Url);

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and what happens is the action on the server is hit but the page posts to Home/Favorite displaying the returned Json. Home/Favorite is not even a view.

Comment: Why does your image have an anchor tag on it pointing to /Home/Favorite?  Look at the HTML produced by that Url.Action.  Get rid of it, use '#'.

Comment: @IanMercer why does my image have an anchor tag? I use the href to call the server side action in the ajax method. Wouldn't me having return false stop that href from being hit anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prevent the default behavior, the link is making a new request for the **Favorite** `Action` refreshing the whole page, getting as response the JSON.

```
$('.Image').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //do stuff here

});
```

Comment: you were right. I thought the return false would prevent it though